# Update a cell in Excel Sheet using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to update the "Email Sent" column once an email has sent. Once an email has been sent I want it to say "Sent" instead of "No"

I'm using the "update a row" action however, can't seem to have it updated. I'm not sure what I should enter for the "Key Value" because email can be sent for multiple rows at once.  This is what I have so far but it is not working:

[image]
[image]

**My Excel table:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "Update a row", you need to specify a key column (the one with a unique id or value) so Power Automate can search a single row and update it.

Field "Key Column" is the column name where said ID is stored.
Field "Key Value" is the value to search for.

For example, in the following table:

| Mentor ID | Email | Email_Sent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | someone@gmail.com | No |
| A002 | someoneelse@gmail.com | No |

If you wanted to update the first row, you'd need to specify Key Column = Mentor ID, and Key Value = A001.